# l lost macros after saving excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel

Am using phpexcel, my code must load an exel template file (this template is using macros for some reason) and it creates a new sheet , filled with some data and save the file.
The problem is that saved file lost macros.
Is there any workaround to keep my macros untouched ?

Comment: nobody can clarify this ?

Comment: There is no workround for xls files using PHPExcel.... it doesn't support macros